# how to check whether jsonobject contains boolean or null value?

Tags: android, json

I am working on json parser. In json response some values contains boolean or null values, then how to check whether it is boolean or null?  For example :   user = false  or user = null . At the time of parsing it gives exception as "user is not jsonobject".

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(query);
JSONObject info = json.getJSONObject("info");
JSONObject user = info.getJSONObject("user");
```

Thanks,
Vishakha.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ingo.optBoolean("user")?

From the SDK documentation for optBoolean:
Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a boolean or can be coerced to a boolean. Returns false otherwise.

Note that null will be treated as a false value in this example.

Comment: I tried this method , but still my app crashes. If any other method is there for checking whether it is null or it is false?. please help me.

Comment: Is it possible that "user" is not a JSON? Can you paste the actual JSON string?

Answer (score 1):

[isNull()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29) you can use `if(json.isNull("user")||your conditions)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are trying to get a JSONArray with getJSONObject(). try json.getJSONArray("info"). I had the same problem that i was trying to do if(object.getJSONObject("string") == null) but it threw an exception when trying to get the object to check for its value, and .optBoolean worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data); 
String user = json.getString("user");
variable.setUser(courses_icon_file_name == null ? "": user);
```